# Xpath not working on HTMLUnit

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, htmlunit-driver

I'm working with Selenium Web Driver, with both Chrome and HTMLUnit. With Chrome, the following code works, but HTMLUnit returns an error saying that the element couldnt be found.

```
SeleniumUtils.goURL(driver, "https://someweb.com");
Thread.sleep(3000); //Added just in case it was loading time
List<WebElement> list = SeleniumUtils.getElements(driver, TrackingPage.getTableContent());
```

That last line will return null, with no elements found. The XPath used is :

```
return By.xpath("//*[@id=\"__xmlview1--idProductsTable-tblBody\"]/tr");
```

Works with Chrome, fails in XPath with HTMLUnit. Any idea?

The driver used is created like this:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
//*[@id='__xmlview1--idProductsTable-tblBody']/tr
```

I have used single quotes here.
It will no difference but you can give it a try and see if it works.
Please do let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried that too and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"__xmlview1--idProductsTable-tblBody\"]/tr"));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The 'SeleniumUtils.getElements' is exactly your code. I don't know how to format it in the comments, you can copy and paste and format it in your IDE. Sorry for the incovenience

`public static List<WebElement> getElements(WebDriver driver, By element) {

   List<WebElement> result = null;

   try {

    result = driver.findElements(element);

   }catch(Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

   }

   return result;

  }`